# Click to display record for specific user in popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I am displaying all the list in the table like below example.

```
 Id  |Name | Email        | Mobileno | Action
  1  |ABC  | abc@gmail.com|1654789523| View Archive
  2  |xyz  | xyz@gmail.com|3214569874| View Archive
```

Now When I am clicking on the view button of id 1 then the popup will display with all the information but my issue is, I am getting only the last user id value in the popup. I mean it's displaying only the records of Id 2.

**list code**

```
        <tbody>
   <?php  $n=1;
           foreach ($cust_personal as $row)  
           {  ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $n;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>    
            <td><?php echo $row->mobileno;?></td>
            <td>
            <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="view(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>"> <span>View</span></a>
            <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="archive(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>"> <span>archive</span></a>
            </td> 
        </tr>
<?php $n++;}?>

    </tbody>
```

**popup code**

```
<div class="profile" id="profile-<?=$row->id;?>" style="display: none;">
//details list
  <table></table>

</div>
```

**js**

```
function view(obj) 
{
    var id = $(obj).data('id');
    $("#profile-"+id).show();  
}
```

Comment: make sure you pop up div should also be inside your foreach loop

Comment: @pradeep, I am using table how can we add the popup code inside foreach? I tried to use after </tr> then it's working but other issue is I am also displaying the table in the popup that will not display.

Comment: u can use another foreach with same variable at another place on the same page ,  but u can place it inside same foreach loop after the tr just before the loop ends

Answer (score 0):

You should use only 1 popup div block and then, when click on button View, put your all information into the popup. Something like this:

```
<div class="profile" id="#show-profile?>" style="display: none;">
</div>

<script>
    function view(obj) 
    {
        var id = $(obj).data('id');
        $("#show-profile).html(
        'Id:' + obj.parent().children().first()
        + 'Name: ' + blah blah
        ');
        $("#show-profile).show();  
    }
</script>
```

This just an example, so you can use this way for fix your issue.
Additonal, you should take `<tbody>` out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Is there any issue with your code? because when I am adding it then it displays something wrong. might be some inverted comma? and  missing ) after argument list

Comment: And I just want to know how the database value will display in this function? becauese I have to display more then 10 column values in this